# Почему при переходе из touch режима эмуляции в обычный выводится код из touch?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Если сейчас загрузиться с режима эмуляции в хроме, а потом перейти в обычный режим, то в консоле выведется 'touch', а нужно, чтобы выводилось simple screen.

https://jsfiddle.net/dwfvb1hy/3/

```
function isTouchDevice() {
    if (isTouch) {
      console.log('touch');
    } else {
      console.log('simple screen');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если посмотреть в консоль браузера, то можно заметить, что после возвращение в обычный режим, в `window` остается `ontouchstart`, поэтому проверка и выдает такой результат.

Вообще это очень сильно зависит от устройства и браузера, если вам нужно определить мобильное устройство, то можно воспользоваться [Device.js](https://www.javascripting.com/view/device-js). Или если есть время, то разобраться с [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/docs)